# How to remove changeset temporarily from VS TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I want to remove my changes temporarily from `VS 2010`. Say, I have checked code into `TFS and changeset# is 100`. But I want code that was prior check in`(prior changeset# 100)`.

How to do this?

I see one option when I do view history, `"Rollback Entire Changeset"`. But I am not sure whether it rollbacks temporary or permanently.
I want it do temporary rollback as I will require changes done in `changeset#100` later.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.